# check user Radio input using input button to return bootbox

Tags: jquery, html, twig

I have a form with a list of Radio's where a user must select the correct answer, from here the user will click a submit button which checks which radio they have selected and returns a bootbox informing them if they ahve selected the correct one before moving them to the next question.

JQuery:

```
{% block onload %}
    $("#useranswer").on("click", function(event){

    var answer = $('[name="answer"]:checked).val();

    if (answer == "answer1") {
        bootbox.dialog({
            closeButton: false,
            onEscape: false,
            title: "the title",
            message: "the message",
            buttons: {
                success:{
                    label: "Next Question",
                    callback: function(result) {
                        if (result) {
                            window.location.href = 'http://localhost/webproject/java/tutorialone.questionfour/';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
    });
{% endblock onload %}
```

HTML/Twig:

```
{% block main %}
    <section class="row">
        <article class="ml-auto col-md-8 mr-auto">
            <p>Which print method is used in a Java program to print on a new line?</p>
            <br><br>
            <form id="uanswer" method="get">
                <input type="radio" name="answer" value="answer1" id="answer1"> System.out.println()<br><br>
                <input type="radio" name="answer" value="answer2" id="answer2"> Console.WriteLine<br><br>
                <input type="radio" name="answer" value="answer3" id="answer3"> printf()<br><br>
                <input type="radio" name="answer" value="answer4" id="answer4"> System.out.ln()<br><br>
                <input type="button" value="Check My Answer" id="useranswer" class="btn btn-large btn-info">
            </form>
        </article>
    </section>
{% endblock main %}
```

I'm unsure how to make this work.

Comment: `$('[name="answer"]:checked)` you are missing a closing `'`.  Typo?

Comment: where would the ' go? just before the end bracket?

Comment: at the end of checked.  You are giving a string to the `$()`.  Since you started the string with `'` it must end with it as well

Comment: That fixed it aha thank you so much

Comment: Alright, i'll vote to close due to typo then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed a `'` from my var declaration.

```
var answer = $('[name="answer"]:checked').val();
```